# start not found for job in /etc/init ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, upstart

I have added my conf file in dir `/etc/init` as

```
author "seaweed"
description "seaweedfs"
start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
limit nofile 1000000 1000000

respawn
chdir /
setuid root
setgid root
console log

exec /root/work/bin/weed -v=0 volume -mserver=18.01.13.10:9333 -ip=88.9.4.92 -dir=/storage -max=2270 -images.fix.orientation=false -pulseSeconds=1
```

When I do sudo `start seaweedfs` I only get error as start command not found?

I am very new to this stuff and i really dont know what the problem is.. My concerns are to run this job in background and also use start stop if needed.

any help will be thankful

Comment: 16.04 uses systemd. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a file in `/etc/systemd/system/{your_service_name}.service`

Add the script below in the file.

```
[Unit]
Description=SeaweedFS Volume
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
LimitNOFILE=1000000
Environment=HOME=/home/root
Environment=LANGUAGE=en_US:en
Environment=LS_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

ExecStart=/opt/go/bin/weed -v=0 volume -mserver=18.01.13.10:9333 -ip=88.9.4.92 -dir=/storage -max=2270 -images.fix.orientation=false -pulseSeconds=1
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
Environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SyslogIdentifier=seaweedfs

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. `systemctl enable {your_service_name}.service`
3. `systemctl {start,status} {your_service_name}.service`

Replace start or status as you like to check for.
This is how We resolved this into a systemd job.